# Jest assertion - object containing a key

Tags: jestjs

In Jest I need to test an expected value which can be either null or an object

```
{
  main: {
    prop1: 'abc',
    prop2: '123',
  }
}
```

but if it is an object, then I don't really care what `main` contains, I don't care about `prop1` or `prop2`. I only need to assert that the object contains a key named `main`.

[Jest reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectobjectcontainingobject) mentions `objectContaining`, but it would still require that I specify at least one of the `props`, thus making my code unnecessarily verbose.

Is there any swift way to achieve an assertion that could be named `objectContainingKey`, like:

`expect(something).toEqual(expect.objectContainingKey('main'))`

Comment: ok, never mind, I found it in https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#tocontainkeykey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming

```js
const something = {
  main: {
    prop1: 'abc',
    prop2: '123',
  }
}
```

Then you can use [objectContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) and [any](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanyconstructor) to check that `something` is an object containing a key `main` which contains an object

```js
expect(something).toEqual(
  expect.objectContaining({
    main: expect.any(Object),
  });
);
```

Comment: An alternative that I find a little clearer: `expect(something).toMatchObject({main: expect.anything()})`

Answer (score 9):

The docs [have something](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers) more suitable and more readable than the accepted answer:

```
expect(obj.main).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: Nice one! I love it!

Comment: this is not 100% correct. If the object is   { myKey: undefined}, then it will fail the test, but the key actually exists in the object. Not having a key in the object and key having the undefined value are two different thing.

Comment: With this approach, if it fails jest will only tell you `expected undefined to be defined`, whereas the accepted answer will show you the whole object, potentially giving a clue to what went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

or you can do it in a way that is a little tricky

```
const something = { main: { prop1: 'abc', prop2: '123' } }

expect(Object.keys(something).toString()).toBe('main')
```

and

```
expect(Object.keys(something.main).toString()).toBe('prop1')
expect(Object.keys(something.main).toString()).toBe('prop2')
```

or

```
expect(Object.keys(something.main))
  .toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['prop1', 'prop2']))
```